# Find the order of $U_{2n}$

Tags: group-theory, totient-function

Let $n$ be an odd integer and let $k$ be the number of elements in $U_n.$ What is the order of $U_{2n}$?

I have said $\left\lvert U_{2n}\right\rvert=\varphi(2n)=\varphi(2)\varphi(n)=\varphi(n)=k.$ (Since $\operatorname{hcf}(2,n)=1$).

Could someone verify whether this is correct or not?

Comment: If  $U_m$ has its standard meaning, you are right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas By $U_n$ I mean the maximal subset of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ which forms a group under multiplication.

Comment: These are also called the units under multiplication modulo $m$. Your calculation is correct, and well explained.